# Laravel Query builder returning null

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to run the query below but I keep getting null return.

```
$result = Order::with(['customers', 'team'])->where('customers_id','=', $custid)->select(sprintf('%s.*', (new Order)->table));
```

Then I changed it to

```
$result = Order::with(['customers', 'team'])->where(function($query) use ($cust) {$query->where('customers_id', $cust);})->select(sprintf('%s.*', (new Order)->table));
```

still returns null.

`customers_id` belongs to the orders table and references the customer's table. I am getting the `$custid` from the URL parameter.

If I replace `$custid` with an integer for example 3, it returns all orders for the customer with id 3. I have spent hours trying to resolve the issue. I have hosted on Heroku and localhost but nothing works.

Comment: Include the code you use to get `$custid`.

Comment: This is a url parameter

I have this in the datatablesactions.blade a button ```href="{{ route('admin.orders.index', ['cid' => $row->id]) }}```

then in my orderscontroller@index

```$cust = $request->cid;

Then this is the output of the querylog

select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as row_count from orders where (customers_id is null) and orders.deleted_at is null) count_row_table []

select orders.* from orders where (customers_id is null) and orders.deleted_at is null []```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the way you're getting the url parameter. Put your url parameter in your method declaration.

Check the Laravel docs under **Dependency Injection & Route Parameters** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#accessing-the-request)

`public function index(Request $request, $custid) {`